# What is the scope of CMake policies?

Tags: cmake

I've got a CMake project with several subdirectories, like this one:

```
dir1
    subdir11
    subdir12
dir2
    subdir21
    subdir22
```

Root CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_subdirectory(dir1)
add_subdirectory(dir2)
```

CMakeLists in dir1 and dir2 are similar:

```
add_subdirectory(subdir11)
add_subdirectory(subdir12)
```

and

```
add_subdirectory(subdir21)
add_subdirectory(subdir22)
```

And CMakeLists in subdirs do actual work.

The file `dir1/subdir12/CMakeLists.txt` sets the `CMP0046` policy to `OLD`:

```
cmake_policy(SET CMP0046 OLD) #silently ignore missing dependencies
```

My question is - will this setting of CMP0046 propagate to `subdir21` and `subdir22` ?

Comment: Don't set the policy to OLD. Fix your code instead. Policies exist so that you can explicitly get NEW behavior. OLD behavior will be removed entirely in a future release.

Comment: Sorry, I can't. My CMake code generates some header files and some .c sources

Comment: That makes no sense. Generating files does not prevent setting CMP0046 to NEW.

Comment: Agree, it doesn't make sense. My goal was to suppress warnings about missing files, I've achieved it with 'OLD' 'CMP0046'. I'd appreciate if you could suggest another method.

Comment: I suggest you create a http://sscce.org/ showing your problem and make a SO post. Setting CMP0046 to OLD is not correct, and I hope no one follows your lead.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. This question is best answered straight [from the documentation](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/wikis/doc/cmake/Policies#policy-stack)...

> Policy settings are scoped using a stack. A new level of the stack is
>   pushed when entering a new subdirectory of the project (with
>   add_subdirectory) and popped when leaving it. Therefore setting a
>   policy in one directory of a project will not affect parent or sibling
>   directories but will affect subdirectories.

For making temporary changes to a specific level, without including sub_directories, you can use

```
cmake_policy(PUSH)
cmake_policy(POP)
```

If you want the policy applied in subdir21 and subdir22 you either need to add it there explicitly or consider adding it to the common parent.

Answer (score 8):

Per the comment for this answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/512695/48776

It's possible to set policy globally with `set(CMAKE_POLICY_DEFAULT_CMP0046 OLD)`

I have tried on different 3.x versions, it works.

Comment: This variable should not be set by a project in CMake code as a way to set its own policies. Details https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_POLICY_DEFAULT_CMPNNNN.html

Comment: @Dmytro any better solution?