# CMake, CMP0046, autogenerated sources. How to suppress warnings?

Tags: cmake

Consider the following toy project for the Visual Studio, built with CMake.

File CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8)
project(CMP0046)

# cmake_policy(SET CMP0046 OLD)   <----

add_executable(an_exec a.cpp)

configure_file(data_file.txt data_file.txt.c @ONLY)
add_custom_command(OUTPUT data_file.txt.c
                   COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} data_file.txt data_file.txt.c -P ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/gen_file.cmake
                   MAIN_DEPENDENCY data_file.txt)
add_dependencies(an_exec data_file.txt.c)
```

File gen_file.cmake

```
if (CMAKE_ARGV2)
    configure_file(${CMAKE_ARGV1} ${CMAKE_ARGV2})
endif()
```

Files `a.cpp` and `data_file.txt` are currently empty because their contents don't matter.

Tree points:

- the C source `data_file.txt.c` is generated from `data_file.txt` with CMake;
- original data file changes during development, and I want to have `data_file.txt.c` automatically regenerated to reflect all recent changes
- I'd like to use this solution in another projects without changes, therefore, I should consider that amount and names of such files vary. For example, these could be OpenCL sources.

The current CMake script doesn't change CMP0046 policy (the commented line marked with an arrow above), and this causes warnings about missing dependencies when I press generate button in the CMake GUI.

I have two goals:

- to avoid these warnings
- avoid appearance of these intermediate autogenerated .c sources in the solution

If I uncomment that line and set CMP0046 to OLD, CMake is quiet. However, I was suggested here: [What is the scope of CMake policies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29123444/what-is-the-scope-of-cmake-policies), that it is incorrect.

I prefer `add_custom_command` over `add_custom_target`, because custom target appears in the generated VS Solution as a separate project. For example, these lines, added to CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_custom_target(data_file_txt_c
                  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} data_file.txt data_file.txt.c -P ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/gen_file.cmake
                  DEPENDS data_file.txt)
add_dependencies(an_exec data_file_txt_c)
```

result in the Visual Studio solution, where a new project is added, named `data_file_txt_c`, which I would like to avoid.

So, what is the best solution?

Comment: From the current state of the question, it is unclear what you really want to do here. `configure_file` will never be able to update files automatically on change, as it requires rerunning CMake. Because of this, the `add_dependency` call is actually useless. You mention that you consider using `add_custom_command`, but what kind of replacement are you doing here that would work with both `configure_file` and `add_custom_command`? Also the reasons for your reluctance to use `add_custom_target` are not clear to me.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm even more confused now. What is the significance of the `configure_file` call in your example? What you need to clarify is when you need your files generated. The answer will vary greatly depending on whether you need code generation at configure time or at build time.

Comment: I need source generation at build time. Agree, my code does it twice, both at configure and at build. I also do not want new VS projects in the generated solution file, related to the generated sources.