# Ignore warnings in external modules when using CMake

Tags: cmake, suppress-warnings, cmake-gui

I am using `CMake GUI` (no version) with `CMake` 3.6.1. I am using an external module with `add_subdirectory` that shows me some warnings that I do not like (because of the annoying pollution):

```
CMake Warning (dev) at D:/Sources/.../external/g3log/latest/Build.cmake:11 (IF):
  Policy CMP0054 is not set: Only interpret if() arguments as variables or
  keywords when unquoted.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0054" for policy
  details.  Use the cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this
  warning.

  Quoted variables like "MSVC" will no longer be dereferenced when the policy
  is set to NEW.  Since the policy is not set the OLD behavior will be used.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  D:/Sources/.../external/g3log/latest/CMakeLists.txt:72 (INCLUDE)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.
```

I want to hide these warnings without touching the external files. `-Wno-dev` would be ok if it will affect only the external module (`g3log`).

I tried using `cmake_policy` like following with no effect:

```
cmake_policy(PUSH)
cmake_policy(SET CMP0054 OLD)
add_subdirectory(${g3log_DIR} ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/../g3log)
cmake_policy(POP)
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29123444/what-is-the-scope-of-cmake-policies

Comment: That sounds like your external module does have a `project()` command. This resets the policies for this sub-module and below. You can try setting [`CMAKE_POLICY_DEFAULT_CMP0054`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_POLICY_DEFAULT_CMPNNNN.html) instead of calling `cmake_policy()`.

Comment: There is a `project (g3log)` indeed. So you are saying is impossible :( ? If you want, you can formulate an answer.

Comment: No. I tried to say `cmake_policy(SET CMP0054 ...)` will not work, but `CMAKE_POLICY_DEFAULT_CMP0054` should. Just haven't setup a test to verify it.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but how? `set(CMAKE_POLICY_DEFAULT_CMP0054, OLD)` ?

Comment: Yes, just without the comma. I've tested it and added an answer accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Turning my comments into an answer*

That sounds like your external module does have a `project()` command. This resets the policies for this sub-module and below.

To demonstrate a possible solution, lets say you have a external project as the following:

**g3log/CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(g3log NONE)

set(VAR1 "Hello World")
set(VAR2 "VAR1")
if ("${VAR2}" STREQUAL "${VAR1}")
    message("CMP0054 old behavior")
endif()
```

You can now set [`CMAKE_POLICY_DEFAULT_CMP0054`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_POLICY_DEFAULT_CMPNNNN.html) to `OLD` (or even better to `NEW`; nobody really wanted the "OLD" behavior) to get rid of the "Policy CMP0054 is not set" warnings you will get with newer versions of CMake:

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)
project(PolicyOverwrite NONE)

set(CMAKE_POLICY_DEFAULT_CMP0054 NEW)
add_subdirectory(g3log)
```

Now you have set a default for policy [CMP0054](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/policy/CMP0054.html) to be used if none is explicitly given in your project or one of the external projects you are using.

Comment: "nobody really wanted the "OLD" behavior" - nobody except this module, g3log, isn't it? `set(CMAKE_POLICY_DEFAULT_CMP0054 NEW)` before `add_subdirectory(g3log)` would change this module's behaviour, isn't it?
So the better answer would be: `set(CMAKE_POLICY_DEFAULT_CMP0054 OLD)
add_subdirectory(${SOURCE_BASE_EXTERNAL}/corealpi/platform/cmake/core ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/corealpi/core)
set(CMAKE_POLICY_DEFAULT_CMP0054 NEW)`

Comment: @Liviu Could you please add/post the g3log CMake script lines in question? I've never came across a case where someone was expecting that something I put in quotes does evaluate again for a variable name (see also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31037882/whats-the-cmake-syntax-to-set-and-use-variables)). So e.g. that `if (CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID STREQUAL "MSVC")` is false, even CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID does contain `MSVC`?

Comment: `IF ("${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID}" MATCHES ".*Clang")` Also [github](https://github.com/KjellKod/g3log/blob/master/Build.cmake), line 23 . I periodically understand and then forget this peculiar syntax.

Comment: @Liviu It's a RegEx for everything that ends with `Clang`. It wants to match against a string, so definitely `NEW`. I don't think they were aware of this bug in older versions of CMake (that `"${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID}"` could evaluate to `1`).

Comment: When I say strange syntax, I do not talk about the regex, but about CMake and quotes. Thank you! I will accept the anwser in a few days, to be sure.