# CMake override policy for subproject

Tags: python, c++, cmake, visibility

My CMake project compiles a Python .so/.dylib extension module linked with a big static library. I want to compile the subproject's static library with hidden visibility for symbols : it would allows the linker (or LTO optimizer) to discard symbols unused by my python module.

The best way to do this would be using `CXX_VISIBILITY_PRESET` and friends on the subproject's static library target.
However, the subproject use policies from 3.1.0 by declaring :

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.1.0)
```

The policy `CMP0063 NEW: Honor visibility properties for all target 
types.` is only introduced from version 3.3 and thus, the set_target_properties have no effects.

My project requires CMake 3.3, but I have no control on the subproject.

I would like to avoid patching the subproject CMakeLists.txt, but currently I see no other way.

Any idea ?

Comment: Instead of using the property, you may simply adjust linker flags [CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/variable/CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS.html).

Comment: It's a compile time option. Ideally I would set CXX_VISIBILITY_PRESET to "hidden" globally and then `set_target_properties(python_module PROPERTIES CXX_VISIBILITY_PRESET default)`. Effectively it set '-fvisibility=hidden' on the compiler flags for the source declaring private symbols.

Comment: If you are sure that subproject would work with `CMP0063` policy, then you may replace `cmake_minimum_required` function for subproject, so it will enable given policy. See [that answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35345933/3440745) about CMake function's replacing.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [`cmake_minimum_required()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/cmake_minimum_required.html) has the following effects on the CMake policies:

> - All policies introduced in the specified version or earlier will be set to use NEW behavior.
> - All policies introduced after the specified version will be unset.

But you can use CMake's [`CMAKE_POLICY_DEFAULT_CMP<NNNN>`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_POLICY_DEFAULT_CMPNNNN.html) global variables to "default for CMake Policy CMP when it is otherwise left unset."

Here is an example:

```
set(CMAKE_POLICY_DEFAULT_CMP0063 NEW)
add_subdirectory(MySubProjDir)
```

**Reference**

- [CMake: ignore the warnings of external modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41695993/cmake-ignore-the-warnings-of-external-modules)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `add_compile_option` to specify the appropriate compiler option.

Comment: Currently, I use `target_compile_options(${TARGET_NAME} PRIVATE -fvisibility=hidden)` on all my targets except the python module.
As the title suggest i'am more interested in a general method to leverage CMake functionalities (policies in CMake language) from the cmake_minimum version of top project, in the subprojects that require a lower version.