# How to use variables and avoid CMP0054 policy violations?

Tags: cmake

We are catching errors during testing for CMP0054 policy violations. An example can be found online at [Build 367](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/noloader/cryptopp/build/1.0.367/job/yp3lip31cotc6o1e).

```
cmake : CMake Warning (dev) at CMakeLists.txt:364 (if):
At line:8 char:5
+     cmake -G "Visual Studio 15 2017" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=$env:configur ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (CMake Warning (...s.txt:364 (if)::String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

  Policy CMP0054 is not set: Only interpret if() arguments as variables or
  keywords when unquoted.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0054" for policy
  details.  Use the cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this
  warning.
  Quoted variables like "MSVC" will no longer be dereferenced when the policy
  is set to NEW.  Since the policy is not set the OLD behavior will be used.
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.
```

It is due to making an if statement like so:

```
if ("${CRYPTOPP_AMD64}" STREQUAL "1" OR "${CRYPTOPP_I386}" STREQUAL "1")
    ...
endif()
```

The statements above are consistent with [What's the CMake syntax to set and use variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31044116/608639), and it was the only thing that seemed to "just work" everywhere, regardless of whether the variable was set, was empty, had a 0 value, had a 1 value or had some other value.

We removed the quotes from the variable to satisfy the god damned policy and all hell broke loose. Now we are lucky to get through a CMake configuration without an error. We tried:

```
if (${CRYPTOPP_AMD64} STREQUAL "1" OR ${CRYPTOPP_I386} STREQUAL "1")
    ...
endif()
```

And:

```
if (${CRYPTOPP_AMD64} STREQUAL 1 OR ${CRYPTOPP_I386} STREQUAL 1)
    ...
endif()
```

And:

```
if (${CRYPTOPP_AMD64} EQUAL 1 OR ${CRYPTOPP_I386} EQUAL 1)
    ...
endif()
```

They mostly lead to a *"CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt... if given arguments..."*. For example, here's testing on Solaris 11:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:507 (if):
  if given arguments:

    "EQUAL" "1" "AND" "NOT" "DISABLE_SSSE3"

  Unknown arguments specified
```

We don't control user machines, so changing a policy and running commands like cmake_policy is out of the question for us. We don't expect users to do anything special. Users are only expected to make a directory, cd into the directory, and then run cmake. That's it.

What is the syntax we should use for variables that works everywhere given the latest changes in CMake?

When we say everywhere, we mean from Cmake 2.8 to Current, and a variable that might be in any state, including set, empty, 0 value, 1 value or an unexpected value.

---

***EDIT***: We are now catching bug reports for the unquoted variables on Windows machines. Yet another damn CMake bug at [Windows CMake failure when compiler path has a space](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/issues/486).

CMake has been in the library for two years. It makes up 18% of the bugs in our bug reporter. It causes a disproportionate number of problems for users.

Comment: @usr1234567 - From the help file: *"The `OLD` behavior of a policy is `deprecated by definition` and may be removed in a future version of CMake."* Asking users to set a policy to one that's being removed is certainly out of the question.

Comment: If you want to check whether value of `CRYPTOPP_AMD64` variable is "1", then use `if(CRYPTOPP_AMD64 STREQUAL "1")`. This is what the policy implies. If value of variable `CRYPTOPP_AMD64` **refers to other variable**, please, elaborate that in the question post.

Comment: Thanks @Tsyvarev - `CRYPTOPP_AMD64` may be undeclared, set, empty, 0 value, 1 value or an unexpected value like "Error". So I'm clear... We should not longer use `${CRYPTOPP_AMD64}` and friends. We should now use `CRYPTOPP_AMD64` without the dollar sign and braces. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, no need to *dereference* variable in `if` clause, use plain variable name without quotes. CMake perfoms "automatic evaluation" in that case. See documentation for [if command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/command/if.html).

Answer (score 8):

There are two solutions:

1. Just set policy `CMP0054` to `NEW`

   ```
   cmake_policy(SET CMP0054 NEW)
   ```

   That would stop CMake version >= 3.1 to try to interpret variables in quotes as variable names again (see also the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41695993/ignore-warnings-in-external-modules-when-using-cmake), nobody really wanted the `OLD` behavior).

   The hint that "the `OLD` behavior of a policy is deprecated by definition and may be removed in a future version of CMake" just means that the CMake developers will sometime in the future remove the legacy code necessary to still support the `OLD` behavior.
2. Change - as @Tsyvarev commented - all `if` statements to just the variable name without the dollar sign and braces

   ```
   if (CRYPTOPP_AMD64 STREQUAL "1" OR CRYPTOPP_I386 STREQUAL "1")
       ...
   endif()
   ```

   That would also work for older versions of CMake.

It's not an option to use the `${ }` variable de-referencing syntax without quotes, because it could end in an empty string (leading to those `if()` syntax errors).

*Note*: As a workaround [CMake modules itself](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/Platform/Windows-MSVC.cmake#L286) are using an "x" prefix for their variable checks. But I think that looks a little weird:

```
if ("x${CRYPTOPP_AMD64}" STREQUAL "x1" OR "x${CRYPTOPP_I386}" STREQUAL "x1")
    ...
endif()
```

*Note*: You only get the `CMP0054` warning if the context of your variable was actually evaluated again (so it's a hint your CMake code will not work in those places).

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set the cmake minimum required version to the one you currently used by adding this command (VERSION 3.15.1 for example):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15.1)
```